# Cannot implicitly convert type Models to string issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I really dont know what went wrong: I was following tutorials on rest web services using asp.net web api and i got this error in `GET(int id)`: 
cannot implicitly convert type `Models.Client` to `string`

here's my code:

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    using (ClientDB db = new ClientDB())
    {
        return db.Clients.FirstOrDefault<Client>(c => c.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Id from the model is type integer and so is `id`
and i also tried `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: This happens because the `return type` of your method is of type `string`, while the actual return type is as the errors states `Models.Client`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note your method's signature. The `return` type is a `string`:

```
public string Get(int id) //this signature shows that you should return a string
```

but you return a `Client` in the method block:

```
return db.Clients.FirstOrDefault<Client>(c => c.Id == id); //you return a Client (or Default) here!
```

Thus you got the error.

You need to change either the method to return `Client`:

```
public Client Get(int id) //change to return Client
```

Or to change the `return` in the block to return `string`

```
return db.Clients.FirstOrDefault<Client>(c => c.Id == id).ToString();
```

For the latter solution beware of `FirstOrDefault` resulting in `null` though. Safer way is:

```
Client client = db.Clients.FirstOrDefault<Client>(c => c.Id == id);
return client == null ? null : client.ToString();
```

In C#6, the syntax for that can be simplified:

```
return db.Clients.FirstOrDefault<Client>(c => c.Id == id)?.ToString();
```

Comment: Thankk youu,  I really didn't notice the return type!

Comment: In C# 6 they can do `?.ToString()` after the `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @juharr true for C#6 solution. ;) why don't I just add it?

Comment: @ian Can you please tell me why the include isn't working(am not allowed to ask question now so Please!): return db.Accounts.Include(c => c.Clients);

Comment: @Guest012393 why Include? O.o I do not know what `Accounts` also... cannot really tell why from the given info

Comment: I have an account for every client, so when displaying the account info I also need to include the client info in the same api, how do i do this? @Ian

Comment: @Guest012393 by creating new `View` or by passing the `Model` which consists of the `Account`